# iOS App Store Rating (Tracking The User's Actions)

Tags: ios, swift

Using the below code i can ask the user to rate the app on the app store

```
if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
   SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()           
} else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Is there a way to know if the user actually rated the application, canceled or clicked later?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is No way.

Comment: Currently this is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that. But if you get a little bit creative you can at least get an idea whether the user is going to leave a rating or not.

For example you could put the `requestReview()` inside an `UIAletController`, asking the user "do you want to rate?", if the tap no there is no point calling the `requestReview()`, but if the tap yes then the likelihood is that they will rate so call `requestReview()`.

Of course this is not the best UX as you are essentially asking the same thing twice, but you can't have it both ways... Hope it helps.