# Is it possible to get the ratings provided by the user to the app through native in app review?

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, mobile

Is there an API to get ratings provided by the user to the app through native in app review? and can we get a hold of the event when the user clicks NOT NOW or CANCLE button?

read through few websites but could not find a clear solution.

Comment: I've never heard of a way to get at the user's rating. Re user declining, some (many?) apps FIRST put up their OWN dialog asking user if they want to leave a review. You have complete control over that dialog. Thus, your app knows if they click YES or NO. If they say NO, the OS is not involved. (Don't have them do anything other than Yes/No; you can't pass any info on to OS, and it would be annoying to user to do something twice.) If they say Yes, THEN you call the platform's native API. (Though they might still cancel at that point, which you won't know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not able to get the user's rating for Andriod or iOS app. Otherwise, developer could encourage users to rate their app by giving rewards. That may **violate** the **Apple App Review Guidelines**: *Apps should not require users to rate the app, review the app, watch videos, download other apps, tap on advertisements, enable tracking... including but not limited to gift cards and codes.* The same goes for Andriod I thought. In iOS, we use [*SKStoreReviewController*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller?language=objc) to get feedback on the app. We cannot modify or inherit it.

I also found some answers similar to this question, such as [iOS App Store Rating (Tracking The User's Actions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041839/ios-app-store-rating-tracking-the-users-actions). Do2 presented a way of popping up an alert to track user's options before presenting SKStoreReviewController. But it may cause poor user experience, right? Maybe we should pay more attention to improving app ratings with right strategies.

Hope it works for you.